# RPM spec file attribute

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

I have a set of files and directories which are to be installed with the rpm spec package

Please advise whether the below is correct to set the user as "ABC" to all the files and directories under deploy

```
%attr(0755,ABC,users) /home/sathya/deploy/*
```

The package is getting installed properly, but all the entities are created as a root user.

Edit:

I found the problem. The issue was with my script running during the post, which touches the files for a purpose. Since the script run as root user, the files are getting owned by root.

THIS IS CLOSED. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The command will have the owner be "`ABC`" and the group "`users`" - do these exist on the target machine?

*Side note*: Having an RPM install into `/home/` probably isn't a good idea.

Comment: Yes, ABC and users exist on the target server. The `/home` is just an example. I am deploying it on my NAS mount pt.